# Actionscript 3.0 sounds accounting

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I have an Array of SoundChannels actively playing.
When new sound is going to play, I append its SoundChannel to this array.
I have to maintain such an array in order to be able to stop all sounds at once.

I would like to remove sound channel from array when it finishes to prevent inifinite growing of my array. But when I catch e=Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, I have no information on sound channel. It is only possible to get Sound as e.target.

Actually, I can maintain Array of pairs (Sound, SoundChannel).
But maybe there exists more light-weight solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need that array :) you can just use SoundMixer.StopAll(); to stop every sound that is playing.

edit: since you want to stop all special sounds, i have a new solution.
first, you create a new actionscript class and you add this code to it.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;

    public class SpecialSoundChannel extends SoundChannel
    {
        var _parent:DisplayObject;

        public function SpecialSoundChannel(Parent:DisplayObject)
        {
            super();

            _parent = Parent;

            _parent.addEventListener("StopSpecialSound", stopChannel);
        }

        public function stopChannel(e:Event):void
        {
            //DO SOME OTHER STUFF YOU WANT DONE.

            stop();
        }
    }
}
```

every time you want to have a special sound added that is not music, you just do it like this:

```
var _sound:SpecialSoundChannel = new SpecialSoundChannel(this);
```

"this" is the class where you play and stop your soundchannel, which i am assuming is the same as where you create your soundchannel and therefore can call it "this". You add the following function to that class.

```
public function stopSpecialSounds():void
{
    var _e:Event = new Event("StopSpecialSound");
    dispatchEvent(_e);
}
```

if you want to stop all special sounds, you just call for this last function.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I don't want to stop every sound. I need stop only sounds from my array. For instance, there maybe some music playing. And it must continue to play when I stop my sounds.

Comment: "I have to maintain such an array in order to be able to stop all sounds at once." looks to me like you want to be able to stop all sounds at once, so the soundMixer can do that for you the moment you want it to, without you having to keep all your soundchannels in an array.

Comment: Well, I have updated my comment. In other words, I'm not going to stop all sounds. I'm going to stop only "special" sounds i.e. all sounds from my array.

Comment: Thanks, Michiel. Beautiful solution!

Comment: glad i was able to help :) and you might want to accept the answer, so this question can be stored as answered.